# Why Babel introduces unused variable when destructuring property from object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

I just looked at compiled script of my source code and I think I noticed something weird.

This ES6 code:

```js
const data = {someProperty:1, someNamedPropery: 1, test:1};
const { 
  someProperty, // Just gets with 'someProperty' peoperty
  someNamedPropery: changedName, // Works same way, but gets with 'changedName' property
  test: changedNameWithDefault = 1, // This one, introduces new variable and then uses it to compare that to void 0
} = data;
```

Compiles to this:

```js
"use strict";

const data = {someProperty:1, someNamedPropery: 1, test:1};
var someProperty = data.someProperty,
    changedName = data.someNamedPropery,
    _data$test = data.test,
    changedNameWithDefault = _data$test === void 0 ? 1 : _data$test;
```

I am curious why Babel introduces new variable `_data$test`. Can't it just be something like this?

```
...
changedNameWithDefault = data.test === void 0 ? 1 : data.test;
```

It still works.

Notice, that new variable introduction happens only when I'm trying to assign default value if key isn't present in `data` variable or is `undefined`.

Does this affect application performance if `data.test` is big enough? And I wonder if Garbage Collector takes care of it (`_data$test` variable).

Comment: One obvious difference between your suggestion and Babel's output: you access the property twice. That _might_ be safe, but Babel's trying to deal with all possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't it just be something like this?

No, but it's slightly subtle why not: If `test` is an *accessor* property, accessing it is a function call. The destructuring code, and Babel's translation of it, will only call the accessor once. Your change would call it twice. Here's an example:

```js
const data = {
    someProperty:1,
    someNamedPropery: 1,
    get test() {
        console.log("  test called");
        return 1;
    },
};

function es2015OriginalCode() {
    const { 
        someProperty,
        someNamedPropery: changedName,
        test: changedNameWithDefault = 1,
    } = data;
    console.log(`  changedNameWithDefault = ${changedNameWithDefault}`);
}

function babelCode() {
    "use strict";

    var someProperty = data.someProperty,
        changedName = data.someNamedPropery,
        _data$test = data.test,
        changedNameWithDefault = _data$test === void 0 ? 1 : _data$test;
    console.log(`  changedNameWithDefault = ${changedNameWithDefault}`);
}

function yourCode() {
    "use strict";

    var someProperty = data.someProperty,
        changedName = data.someNamedPropery,
        changedNameWithDefault = data.test === void 0 ? 1 : data.test;
    console.log(`  changedNameWithDefault = ${changedNameWithDefault}`);
}

console.log("ES2015 original code:");
es2015OriginalCode();
console.log("Babel's code:");
babelCode();
console.log("Your code:");
yourCode();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

While we can tell looking at the code that `test` isn't an accessor property in that specific example, the code transformations don't usually work with that much context, so this is the safer general case way to translate that code.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Can you write example of ~accessor~ propery? So I can look at it?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze - :-) I literally just updated the answer with a Stack Snippet showing one, hit refresh to see it. What I've done there is one way to define an accessor property (in this case, with just a *getter*, no *setter*). You can also do it with [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). More on the way I did it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions) (also MDN).

Comment: Now everything seems legit. As I see you're very experienced Developer. Can you answer me if my code affects overall app performance? If `data.test` property is big enogh or not?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze - It's impossible to know in the general case. The accessor might be something *really, really fast* like a getter that just returns a private field's value, or it might be something *possibly quite slow* like `innerHTML`. :-) But the extra var is extremely unlikely to have any negative impact, so it's right that Babel uses it. But separately, it's not just performance, it's *correctness*. Sometimes accessors do things (like logging that they've been used) and the code would log twice if it didn't use the temp variable. Or sometimes they change what they do each call.